# How to replace old notification with newly received notification, instead of creating a stack of notifications in the notification tray?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am facing an issue with notifications in the notification panel. I have a requirement to clear old notification if it exists in notification when received a new one when the app is in the background. What can I do or how can I replace old notification with new one. Or there are any possibilities to launch app/activity on the notification received if app is in the background or killed?
this is my code for notification.

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentTitle(title);
        builder.setContentText(message);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);

        builder.setLights(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary), 50, 50);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification);
      builder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
        builder.setVibrate(new long[]{500, 500});

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LauncherActivity.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(notification_id, builder.build());
```

Comment: Just use the same notification ID.

Comment: share your code for build notification.

Comment: set a notification id to the old notification. when new notification come cancel the notification using notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID); then show the new notifiction

Comment: @RituSumanMohanty how can i handle notification id if my app is in background or killed?, i need to replace old one with new one when app is in background or killed.

Answer (score 1):

Only notificationID, same

```
 notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```